# cucumber options are being ignored from docker run in jenkinsfile but not in local

Tags: java, docker, cucumber, dockerfile, cucumber-java

When I launch cucumber appium tests in local with this arguments:

`-ea -Dplatform=android -Dcucumber.options="--tags @mytag"`

it works, but when I launch the same from a `docker run`, it ignores the cucumber options.

I need to launch it from a Jenkins job and run it in docker.

In my Jenkinsfile:

`sh "docker run --env JAVA_OPTS='-ea -Dplatform=$platform -Dcucumber.options=$cucumberOptions'...`

In the Jenkins pipeline log:

`docker run --env 'JAVA_OPTS=-ea -Dplatform=android -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Check_Pricing_Payment_Org"'...`

My TestTunner class:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/functionalTests/"},
        plugin = {"pretty","json:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json","html:target/cucumber-reports/htmlReports.html" },
        glue= {"stepDefinitions"}
        )
public class TestRunner {

}
```

Any help or clue will be appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**

As a workaround, we are now using this in our Jenkinsfile:

```
script {
                if (env.STEP_TO_RUN.toBoolean()) {
                    stage('First satage') {
                        withMaven(maven:'mvn') {
                            sh 'export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="whatevercredentials.json" && mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @MyTag --tags @OtherTag"'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And in our CI job `STEP_TO_RUN` was added as a chain boolean parameter.

This way we made it work in gcloud. Hope this helps someone!